# Numpy PMT Function

Tags: python, numpy

From my understanding, the `np.pmt` uses the 30/360 rule. What if we wanted to use actual/360 or 30/365. Are their any other alternative libraries we can use?

Comment: `pmt` can only compute amortizations over equal periods.  If the periods are unequal (as in actual/360) you'd have to do something different.

Comment: yea i'm googling it and trying to find alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy's financial functions have been moved to a separate package, numpy_financial.

To be precise, it is incorrect to say that `pmt()` uses the 30/360 day count: `pmt` does not use dates at all, but "thinks" in terms of periods, and assumes that all periods have the same length.

This practically means that it corresponds to a 30/360 calculation, but, if your periods are years, it is also the same as actual/actual.

I posted a question [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/61097/how-to-model-fixed-rate-loans-or-mortgages-with-act-365-but-constant-payment) on how to model fixed-rate loans when the interest is calculated as act/365, as it practically is in most, if not all, cases. The problem there (example in the link) is that, if you keep your monthly payment constant but then calculate interest on act/365 (which is what tends to happen for most consumer loans/mortgages) you can end up not amortising the debt in full by the last period, but needing a period more. The difference is small, so, in most practical cases, it will make little to no difference.